# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am trying a simple MVC example in spring but getting 404 error when I load the url "/ModelAndViewDemo/listUsers". I get the below exception. I tried many solutions from similar questions but not working. Please advise.

> Sep 09, 2017 8:54:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 
>      noHandlerFound
>      WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI 
>      [/ModelAndViewDemo/listUsers] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher

Below is my code:

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.manjosh.*" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

controller class:

```
package com.manjosh.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.manjosh.model.User;
import com.manjosh.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listusers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView registerSuccess() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("UserList");
        List<User> userlist = userService.getUserList();
        modelAndView.addObject("userList", userlist);
        return modelAndView;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you map your Controller to `/listusers`, but you call `/listUsers`
either change the mapping to `/listUsers` or call `/listusers`

Comment: I called url "http://localhost:8080/ModelAndViewDemo/listusers" but still getting the same error.

Comment: what if you call only `/listusers` without `ModelAndViewDemo`?

Comment: @manjosh how do you deploy your app? and what container do you use?

Comment: I am using apache tomcat v8 server. Running this code in eclipse. I tried without ModelAndViewDemo and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The dispatcher-servlet xml was missing a "/" in the InternalResourceViewResolver property. I added the "/" and it fixed the issue.

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was with incorrect base package. So the package name should match the packages which you have defined.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springdemo.controller" />
```

changed `org` to `com` and it worked.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springdemo.controller" />
```